# Get only New Company name for each month

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to get list of new companies each month and count of the documents received for that company. Only new company which never came previous month**s** should get listed every month in the result.

Data:

```
DocID   CreateDate  Company
101     2022-12-21  Kolmar
102     2022-12-22  Sams
103     2023-01-05  ABC
104     2023-01-05  Trading
105     2023-01-06  Trading
106     2023-01-18  Kolmar
107     2023-01-23  Kolmar
108     2023-01-27  Global
109     2023-05-08  BROKER
110     2023-06-14  bp
111     2023-06-15  bp
112     2023-07-11  Citron
113     2023-08-11  Citron
```

Result which I am looking for is as below

```
DocID   CreateDate  Company             count 
101     2022-12-21  Kolmar              1
102     2022-12-22  Sams                1
103     2023-01-05  ABC                 1
104     2023-01-05  Trading             2
108     2023-01-27  Global              1
109     2023-05-08  BROKER              1
110     2023-06-14  bp                  2
112     2023-07-11  Citron              1
```

104 and 105 both are from Trading, so count will be 2

106 and 107 should not come as Kolmar company record already came in Dec 2022, only new company which never came before should get listed every month in the result.

110 & 111 both are from bp, so count will be 2

112 should not come as Citron company record already came in July 2023, only new company which never came before should get listed every month in the result.

Answer (score 1):

Use below approach

```
SELECT MIN(DocID) AS DocIS, MIN(CreateDate) AS CreateDate, Company, COUNT(*) AS `Count`
FROM (
  SELECT *, ARRAY_AGG(Company) OVER prev AS Comanies,
  FROM your_table
  WINDOW prev AS (
    ORDER BY EXTRACT(year FROM DATE(CreateDate)) * 12 + EXTRACT(month FROM DATE(CreateDate)) 
    RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
  )
)
WHERE NOT Company IN UNNEST(Comanies)
GROUP BY Company
ORDER BY CreateDate
```

if applied to data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Mikhail, This is perfect. I just want to understand the logic inside WINDOW. If you don't mind could you help me to understand that ?

Comment: it translates YEAR-MONTH into consecutive integers (12xYEAR+MONTH) so then RANGE can be used to define window of all months before month of given row